# Spring boot custom exception not getting printed in logs

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, custom-exceptions

I am trying to implement a custom exception for my Spring boot REST project. The custom exception gets called but shows no impact in the way error message is displayed.

This is the POJO I'm using for my custom errors:

```java
public class ApiError {
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;
    private List<String> errors;

    public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, List<String> errors) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, String error) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        errors = Arrays.asList(error);
    }
}
```

This is the exception handler I wrote:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Custom exception!!");
        //List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        //details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        //System.out.println("Localize message:: "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        // ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),

        //request.getDescription(false));
        ApiError error = new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,"Server Error", request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I'm defined the following method within my controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/model", params = "number", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
List<Model> getModel(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value = "codeNumber") String number) throws Exception{

    List<Model> model = null;
    try {
        model = niiService.getModel(number);
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        new Exception(e);
    }
    return model;
}
```

However, in stead of my custom POJO, I'm seeing the following exception:

```java
{
    "timestamp": 1547013989124,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.",
    "path": "/model"
}
```

I was expecting the  following JSON structure in stead:

```java
{
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Server Error"
    ..
}
```

Please let me know, what I am missing to get the error response in the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `throw` in front of the custom exception.
Also make sure that you are catching the right exception inside your controller.

Change

```
catch (RuntimeException e) {
   //custom exception
    new Exception(e);
}
```

To

```
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    //custom exception
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. But I still dont see any changes in the way my output message is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I missed adding getter and setter to APIError class. Hence, the response was not coming in the way I expected.